# Java DOM Parse and Delete Node

Tags: java, xslt, dom, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

In the below XML I need to search for the tag **attrGroupMany name="allergenRelatedInformation"** and **delete all the child nodes () except the first one under it**.

Not sure if XSLT/Java DOM is the best way to achieve this..please help.

```
 XPathExpression delExpr = xpath.compile("//flexTM/attrGroupMany[starts-with(@name,'allergenRelatedInformation')]/row");
 Object obj = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList row = (NodeList) obj;

 for(int i = 1; i < row.getLength(); i++)

        {

            Node attr = row.item(i);

            Element e = (Element) attr;

            System.out.println(row.item(i).getParentNode().getNodeName());

            row.item(1).getParentNode().removeChild(e);
            doc.normalize();
            i-- }
```

```html
      <attrGroupMany name="manufacturer">
                  <row>
                     <attr name="gln">123456</attr>
                     <attr name="name">ABC Inc</attr>
                  </row>
               </attrGroupMany>
               <attrGroupMany name="allergenRelatedInformation">
                  <row>
                     <attr name="allergenSpecificationAgency">FDA</attr>
                     <attr name="allergenSpecificationName">BIG 8</attr>
                     <attrGroupMany name="allergen">
                        <row>
                           <attr name="allergenTypeCode">AC</attr>
                           <attr name="levelOfContainmentCode">FREE_FROM</attr>
                        </row>
                     </attrGroupMany>
                  </row>
                  <row>
                     <attr name="allergenSpecificationAgency">FDA</attr>
                     <attr name="allergenSpecificationName">BIG 8</attr>
                     <attrGroupMany name="allergen">
                        <row>
                           <attr name="allergenTypeCode">AE</attr>
                           <attr name="levelOfContainmentCode">FREE_FROM</attr>
                        </row>
                     </attrGroupMany>
                  </row>
                  <row>
                     <attr name="allergenSpecificationAgency">FDA</attr>
                     <attr name="allergenSpecificationName">BIG 8</attr>
                     <attrGroupMany name="allergen">
                        <row>
                           <attr name="allergenTypeCode">AF</attr>
                           <attr name="levelOfContainmentCode">FREE_FROM</attr>
                        </row>
                     </attrGroupMany>
                  </row>
                  <row>
                     <attr name="allergenSpecificationAgency">FDA</attr>
                     <attr name="allergenSpecificationName">BIG 8</attr>
                     <attrGroupMany name="allergen">
                        <row>
                           <attr name="allergenTypeCode">AM</attr>
                           <attr name="levelOfContainmentCode">FREE_FROM</attr>
                        </row>
                     </attrGroupMany>
                  </row>
               
                 
               </attrGroupMany>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is the best option if you expect output in xml not required to do further processing. Otherwise JDOM is an option to parse node you are looking for and do the required business logic in later point in same java code.

Comment: Can you please show me how to navigate in my case using JDOM? Thanks much.

Comment: What is the output xml that you are expecting from your program?